# Cryptic errors in AppEngine deployment

Tags: google-app-engine

Deployments to AppEngine with no code changes are suddenly failing with a cryptic error message:

```
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
WARNING: Deployment of service [default] will ignore the skip_files field in the configuration file, because the image has already been built.
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...
...........................failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Deployment Manager operation failed, name: operation-1513231070597-56046906d0f88-da77cf52-0e00ca2f, error: [{"code":"CONDITION_NOT_MET","location":"/deployments/aef-default-50474e3/resources/aef-default-50474e3-00it->$.properties","message":"\"/properties/metadata/items/12/value\": domain: validation; keyword: type; message: instance does not match any allowed primitive type; allowed: [\"string\"]; found: \"number\""}]
Exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the version being passed to the `deploy` command being parsed as a number/integer instead of a string. The fix is to ensure that this is passed as a string.

NOTE: If you are automatically generating the version based on a truncated git hash it's entirely possible to generate a version that will be parsed as a number, e.g: the hash `50474e3` will be treated as scientific notation.